# Statistics: Maximum error of .05 with 90% confidence

Tags: statistics

What size sample is required to have a maximum error of .05 with 90% confidence for the proportion of students who will vote?

Please help.

Comment: Can you show some of your own work and change the title to something more descriptive?

Comment: By .05, do you mean .05 students or .05 the measured amount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p$ be the probability that a student votes, and let $X$ be the number of students in the group of $n$ who vote. Then $X$ has binomial distribution, with mean $np$, and variance $np(1-p)$.

Let $Y=\frac{X}{n}$. Then $Y$ is the sample proportion of the students who vote. It is standard that $Y$ has mean $p$ and variance $\frac{p(1-p)}{n}$.

We don't know $p$, so let's be pessimistic. The largest value of $p(1-p)$ occurs when $p=\frac{1}{2}$. This value is $\frac{1}{4}$. (Actually, $p(1-p)$ remains remarkably close to $\frac{1}{4}$ even for $p$ not very close to $\frac{1}{2}$.)

So let us assume that $Y$ has variance $\frac{1}{4n}$, and therefore standard deviation $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$. The sample size will be fairly large, so $Y$ can be approximated by a **normal** distribution with mean $p$ and standard deviation
$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$.

We want, with probability $0.90$, to have 
$$|Y-p|\lt 0.05.$$
Note that $0.05$ is $(0.05)(2\sqrt{n})$ "standard deviation units."

Look at the place in the table of the standard normal that has $0.05$ in the right tail, that is, the place $z$ such that $\Pr(Z\le z)=0.95$.   We want $0.05$ in the right tail, because if we want the same amount in the right and left tail, that amount should be $0.10$, since we want probability $0.90$ of being between the two tails.  Look at a table of the standard normal. We find that $z\approx1.645$. So we want 
$$(0.05)(2\sqrt{n})\approx 1.645.$$ 
From this we can find the suitable $n$.